# Add burger Icon to bootstrap sidebar

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sidebar

I am trying to add burger menu to my sidebar.
I am using bootstrap sidebar - version 3.3.7 and my bootstrap.min.css is copy to my folder:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
```

The code:

```
const contentHeader = (
    <span>
       <a href="#" onClick={this.menuButtonClick}>
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger">=</span>
       </a>
       <span> My Site - {this.state.selected}</span>
  </span>);
```

when i am running the web site I can not see the Icon, I tried to debug the site
I sew that this elements is empty, when I edited the element and I add the class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger", the burger Icon appeared.

[image of the debug of the element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3c9f3.png)

how can I make the Icon to appear all the time?

Comment: provide code please

Comment: Is `contentHeader` something like JSX? If so, I think you have to use `className` rather than `class` as `class` is a reserved word in JavaScript, e.g. `<span className="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger">=</span>`

Comment: thank you! i changed the class to class name and it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you're using JSX + React from that syntax, in which case you need to use className not class in the html attribute.

I recommend using Atom editor, which should highlight that issue for you.